# Storing a sequence of dataframes with associated parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can someone advice me the best approach to the following problem:

I have a sequence of dataframes (3 by 16 tables) with 4 parameters (preset variables) associated with each dataframe. I need to do calculations on each dataframe using corresponding parameters. What would be the best data structure to store such sequence? What comes to mind is a dictionary of dataframes with parameters as composite index but such structure seems rather cumbersome and I am not sure how easy it will be to access individual components of the index. Another option is to add parameters as meta data to each dataframe but again I am not sure whether it will convenient to handle. Then there is a "brute force" way to add each parameter as a column to each dataframe with setting each column to single value - seems ugly. What would be "correct" way of handling such case? Just to clarify: a sequence of dataframes (same dimensions) and 4 member arrays associated with each of them. What would be the best data structure to store them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are the "4 parameters (preset variables)"? Are they functions? Are they column names? Are they values? It would be helpful if you could show some sample data, both of your frames and associated member arrays.

Comment: They are values. Will add a sample set shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink things:

```
frames = [
    {
        'df': df1,
        'param1': param1,
        'param2': param2,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

```
for frame in frames:
    pd.something(frame['df'], frame['param1'])
    ...
```